# Ending of The Place Beyond the Pines

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-place-beyond-the-pines

In the Ending of [The Place Beyond the Pines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Place_Beyond_the_Pines), did the kid run away from home because of he assaulted and kidnapped Avery or did he run away because he felt a connection with his father and the image of taking to the road on a motorbike?

Or was it a bit of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe his motivation for beginning a life as a traveler can be significantly attributed to the absence of his father in his life, and the connection the motorcycle will provide to him. It is seen as a symbol of his late father - one that can provide guidance in his life like a father who is present normally would.

However, the dramatic events that took place certainly were a factor in his decision to leave. The act of leaving Cross unharmed, at the peak of the escalating conflict, implies a desire to forgive and forget, and leave his life behind.